# Send mail every so often

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to send an email every so often from python. My situation is the next:

I have a database that receives sensor values ​​such as temperature, humidity, pressure, etc. So the database is updated every so often, in my case data is sent every 1 minute to the database, what I try to do is that when the temperature passes a certain value, for example 26 ° C, sending mail stops for example 10 or 20 minutes and send another one in case the temperature stays above 26. I managed to send the mail, but my situation is that it does not stop and sends mails without stopping while the value of the temperature is above 26 ° C.

**This is the code:**

```
dataSQL = []
sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'DB')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT value,timestamp FROM sensorParser where sensor='TC'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    dataSQL.append(list(row))
    labels = ['value','timestamp']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
    X = df['timestamp']
    Y = df['value'].astype(float)


    if (float(df['value'][0]) > 26):
        email = 'email1@gmail.com'
        password = 'pass'
        send_to_email = 'email2@gmail.com'
        subject = 'ALERTA!!!! SENSORES'
        message = 'Los valores de las variables criticas han superado el limite'
        file_location = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\prograpython\\image.jpg'

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = email
        msg['To'] = send_to_email
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

        filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
        attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

        msg.attach(part)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, password)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
        server.quit()
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `import time` into the program and save the time value when the email is sent. Then you can add a check wether ten minutes have passed since the time was saved into the if-statement like this:

```py
import time

timestamp = 0
# ... your code

if (float(df['value'][0]) > 26) and (timestamp == 0 or time.time() - timestamp > 600):
    timestamp = time.time()    
    # ... your code
```

`time.time()` outputs the so-called unix time, which is the number of seconds that have passed since the 1st of January 1970. In the new expression for the if-statement you also check wether more than 600 seconds have passed since you last called the code in the statement, you can change the number of seconds to fit your needs.

Feel free to ask if any further questions should arise.

PS: Please limit the code you share to what is necessary, it makes the question more friendly-looking and easier to read :)

Comment: Did this help? If not, please tell me what the issue with it is, otherwise it would be nice if you could accept the answer.

Comment: Hello, E. Staikov, Sorry for the delay, I tried the code the way you told me, the code was sent but when it is sent, the program is stopped, just send one and it stops